# Can't implement sticky footer due to height:100% issues

Tags: html, css, height, sticky-footer

My site looks fine for pages with [long content](http://www.michigangurudwara.com/wordpress/), but the footer moves up on pages with [short content](http://www.michigangurudwara.com/wordpress/youth-camp/) (EDIT: The links now show a working correct sticky footer). I've tried multiple solutions, but I can't get any of them to work (not working here is either the footer isn't sticky, or it appears in the middle of the page). I've tried [this solution](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) and [this one](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) (I've removed both solutions so I can start fresh). For example, if you go into chrome developer tools or firebug and add `height:100%` to the #wrapper div (which is essentially the first step to getting this to work), the height extends past 100% and the footer isn't at the bottom.

The basic div structure is as follows:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="post"></div> <!-- floats left -->
      <div id="sidebar></div> <!-- floats right -->
      <div style="clear:both"></div> <!-- clear hack -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Here's the CSS for the relevant divs:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-width:900px;
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
#content {
    -moz-border-radius: 11px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
    border-radius: 11px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width:800px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 3px #C0C0C0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 3px #C0C0C0;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 3px #C0C0C0;
}
#footer {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #101010;
    height: 14em;
    color: white;
}

/* These two are probably less important */
#sidebar {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 15px 25px;

    -moz-border-radius: 11px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
    border-radius: 11px;
    /*IE 7 AND 8 DO NOT SUPPORT BORDER RADIUS*/
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #000000;
    /*IE 7 AND 8 DO NOT SUPPORT BLUR PROPERTY OF SHADOWS*/
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr = '#ffffff', endColorstr = '#dcedeb');
    /*INNER ELEMENTS MUST NOT BREAK THIS ELEMENTS BOUNDARIES*/
    /*Element must have a height (not auto)*/
    /*All filters must be placed together*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr = '#ffffff', endColorstr = '#dcedeb')";
    /*Element must have a height (not auto)*/
    /*All filters must be placed together*/
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #dcedeb);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #dcedeb);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #dcedeb);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#dcedeb));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #dcedeb);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #dcedeb);
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
/*Use "background-clip: padding-box" when using rounded corners to avoid the gradient bleeding through the corners*/
/*--IE9 WILL PLACE THE FILTER ON TOP OF THE ROUNDED CORNERS--*/
}
.post {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Can anyone use something like firebug or CDT to figure out why the height 100% doesn't work and how I can get a sticky footer?

EDIT:

After implementing Ryan Fait's solution as described by @ajkochanowicz, this is how the page looks:
[image]

You can see that the grey background (which is the background of the #container div) doesn't stretch to the bottom of the #wrapper div, even though both have `height: 100%`.

Comment: Rather than having us poke around your site, can you post your CSS as well? Hard to solve this without it.

Comment: @ajkochanowicz Ok, give me a sec, I'll post the CSS for the divs I've posted.

Comment: (In response to your update) that is because the wrapper is stretching. Not the container. Set the background of your wrapper to gray instead of the container.

Comment: @ajkochanowicz Could you clarify that? How can I get the container to fill the wrapper (at least up to the footer)?

Comment: You don't need it to if you just want the gray to go all the way down. Do exactly what you did before but put the gray background color on the #wrapper, not the #container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear *which* solution you're using here, so it's hard to tell you what you're doing wrong.

However, I've had success with [Ryan Fait's solution](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) and I don't see any of that code here.

If you're not too far into your site development, you can download [Kickstrap](http://getkickstrap.com) which has this plugged in and working already.

Otherwise, you'll need to have this CSS

```
* { margin: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; }
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px;
}
#footer, #push { height: 142px; }
```

Then add the `#push` div to your markup as such:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="post"></div> <!-- floats left -->
      <div id="sidebar></div> <!-- floats right -->
      <div style="clear:both"></div> <!-- clear hack -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Also don't forget to edit the "142px" value to match your desired footer height.

**EDIT** 
To clarify the difference between a fixed and sticky footer, here is a fixed footer:
http://jsfiddle.net/y48Su/

And here is a sticky footer implemented with Ryan Fait's solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/X6UB7/

Comment: Take a look at my edit in the question. I've made the changes using chrome developer tools and taken a screenshot so that anyone looking at the site now won't see something different than what you saw. Essentially this solution is close, but the #container div doesn't stretch to the bottom of the #wrapper div.

Comment: I've responded in the comments of your original question. Set the wrapper to have a gray background, not the container.

Comment: Brilliant. I'll make the changes live and then accept your answer if everything looks alright.

Comment: Check out the two pages again. I've implemented the sticky footer like you said and the short content page looks fine, but the long content one isn't.

Comment: I think if I take out `height: 100%` and leave `min-height: 100%` it works, but since I don't understand why, I'm hesitant to do that.

Comment: I've accepted the answer because everything looks fine to me, but I did end up removing the `height: 100%` (which is why it looks fine to you now). I hope it doesn't cause problems with some browsers in the future...

Comment: Was height: 100% causing a problem? Why remove it?

Comment: Yea, with height: 100%, the sticky footer was in the middle of the page for the long content page. Removing it fixed the issue, as min-height: 100% was still there.

Answer (score -1):

#### You can do this way:

```css
body {height: auto; padding-bottom: 160px;}
#footer {position: fixed; bottom: 0;}
```

Comment: Check it out @gsingh2011 I tried and then posted this answer. :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar You probably tried it on the page with the short content, but if you try it on the page with the long content, it's not a sticky footer.

Comment: Both short and long content I tried. I actually tried on the long content only.

Comment: @PraveenKumar is right, it works. Don't forget to change the `body`. +1

Comment: @PraveenKumar, a fixed footer sticks to the bottom of the window. A sticky footer sticks to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Vucko What do you mean, "works"? If the page is long, the footer will stick to the bottom of the window even at the top of the page. That's not what a sticky footer does. If gsingh2011 wants that instead, cool. But this does not "work" as the problem is stated.